# Using email python library to get attachment name doesn't work

Tags: python, email, outlook, imaplib

here's what my message details looks like:

[image]

I used the following python code to get attached file name from this mail:

```
import email
mail = email.message_from_string(bytes.decode(email_body))
if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
    continue
for part in mail.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        continue
    if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
        continue
    fileName1 = part.get_filename()
    print(fileName1)
```

It prints None instead of the attachment name. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only thing you want to do is extract the filename, you can use

```
for part in mail.walk():
     if part.get_content_disposition() == 'attachment':
          fileName1 = part.get_filename()
```

This way you are not messing with other parts of the message, only with the attachment(s).

Comment: Also depending on how extensively you want to search for attachments, it is also possible to attach files (from my experience, images mostly) as inline. In that case you might also want to look for `part`s having `Content-Disposition` as `inline`. But be careful, as also `text` or `html`  can have disposition `inline`